# How can I trigger a Jenkins job based on what is essentially a true / false state?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, automated-tests

I have two sets of Jenkins jobs to run end-to-end tests - one for each of two database platforms.

We only have one web application server, so we would like to switch out the database platform once or twice a day.

Currently, with only one database platform in place, the end-to-end test job triggers upon a successful check-in. However, with two sets of end-to-end test jobs, we would like to trigger the appropriate set of jobs depending on which database is in place. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Several different ways to do it, too.

**If you have a single job that can run either set of tests**

1. The simplest to grok is to use a build step to figure out the value of the true / false state and set it into an environment variable, which subsequent steps can use. This is a good way to prototype it, before moving onto easier-to-maintain or more flexible alternatives.
2. You can use a build parameter to pass the value to the job. The Jenkins Parameterized Build plugin provides a few interfaces for this: you can do it via the GUI, via the rest API, or via a post-build step in another job.
3. You can use a groovy script in combination with Pipeline / Jenkins 2 to choose which build node (or step) to run. This logic can go into your source control as a Jenkins file.

There are a few other ways of doing it, but those are the ones to choose from initially. I suggest going with #1 for prototyping, then choose between the other two based on whether or not you already use Pipeline / Jenkins 2.

**If you have two jobs and need to choose between them**

The Pipeline / Jenkins 2 solution works well here. In Jenkins 1, you can use the Parameterized Build plugin which can trigger builds based on job status (so you if the "is it mongoDb" job fails then you run the SQL tests, etc.), but the Pipeline option is what I'd recommend.